# Return sum of previous rows from a specified date

Tags: sql

I'm developing a report to display non routine fidings related to aircraft scheduled maintenance tasks. However, in order to do statistical analysis (weibull) i need to return the sum of the aircraft total hours and aircraft total cycles when the scheduled maintenance task was accomplished.

There are two tables that i need to join.

The first one (aircraft maintenance tasks accomplishment) is listed as follows as its code too.
The second one (Aircraft_Actual_Flights) shows every flights that the aircraft has performed.

I have already tried to use Over  Partition By, but it only returned the sum of the entire Flight Hours and Cycles Columns.

1º table (aircraft maintenance tasks accomplishment) and its code:

```
EO        AC    ORDER_CATEGORY  WO  ACCOMPLISHED_DATE
SVC-1   XX-XXX      WO        375983    07/04/2019
SVC-1   XX-XXX      WO        379384    08/04/2019
SVC-1   XX-XXX      WO        380459    21/04/2019
SVC-1   XX-XXX      WO        376196    25/04/2019
```

```
SELECT EO,
AC,
ORDER_CATEGORY,
ORDER_NO,
RESET_DATE AS "ACCOMPLISHED_DATE"

FROM ODB.ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE

WHERE EO = 'A32X-05-00-00-SVC-1'

AND AC = 'XX-XXX'

AND RESET_DATE BETWEEN 07/04/2019 AND 08/04/2019
```

2º table (Aircraft_Actual_Flights) and its code:

```
AC     FLIGH_DATE   FLIGHT_HOURS    CYCLES
XX-XXX  07/04/2019         2          1
XX-XXX  07/04/2019         2          1
XX-XXX  07/04/2019         3          1
XX-XXX  07/04/2019         1          1
XX-XXX  07/04/2019         1          1
XX-XXX  08/04/2019         6          1
XX-XXX  21/04/2019         5          1
XX-XXX  21/04/2019         2          1
XX-XXX  25/04/2019         1          1
```

```
SELECT AC,
FLIGHT_DATE,
FLIGHT_HOURS,
CYCLES

FROM ODB.AC_ACTUAL_FLIGHTS

AND AC = 'XX-XXX'
```

When i do the join, it is only displaying the sum of total flight hours and total cycles, but it should be returning the sum of the flights until the the date of accomplishment.

```
SELECT A.EO,
A.AC,
A.ORDER_CATEGORY,
A.ORDER_NO,
A.RESET_DATE AS "ACCOMPLISHED_DATE"
SUM(B.FLIGHT_HOURS) OVER(PARTITION BY B.AC) AS "TOTAL FH",
SUM(B.CYCLES) OVER(PARTITION BY B.AC) AS "TOTAL FC"

FROM ODB.ENGINEERING_COMPLIANCE A
LEFT JOIN ODB.AC_ACTUAL_FLIGHTS B
ON A.AC = B.AC

WHERE EO = 'A32X-05-00-00-SVC-1'

AND AC = 'XX-XXX'

AND RESET_DATE >= SYSDATE-7
```

```
EO  AC  ORDER_CATEGORY  WO  ACCOMPLISHED_DATE   TOTAL FH    TOTAL FC
SVC-1   XX-XXX  WO  375983  20/04/2019  23  9
SVC-1   XX-XXX  WO  379384  23/04/2019  23  9
SVC-1   XX-XXX  WO  380459  25/04/2019  23  9
SVC-1   XX-XXX  WO  376196  26/04/2019  23  9
```

Note that 23 is the total Flight hour and 9 is the total flight cycles of the aircraft XX-XXX. It should have a clause that sum the number of rows (flight hours and flight cycles) from the date of accomplishment. Something similar to this: sum when flight_date <= reset_date.

Guys, could you please help me solving this issue?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it appeared this way in the code, but your `BETWEEN` keyword is spelled wrong, which would throw the dates off. Same as `FLIGHT_DATE` in the database.

Comment: That wasn't the main issue of the question, but i've corrected it. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression to get the distinct dates then join all 3 up in the select.

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE(EO varchar(20), AC varchar(20), AccompDate datetime)
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(AC varchar(20), FlyDate datetime, FHours int, FCycles int)

INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES ('SVC-1', 'XX-XXX', '2019-04-07')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES ('SVC-1', 'XX-XXX', '2019-04-08')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES ('SVC-1', 'XX-XXX', '2019-04-21')
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES ('SVC-1', 'XX-XXX', '2019-04-25')   

INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-07', 2 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-07', 2 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-07', 3 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-07', 1 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-07', 1 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-08', 6 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-21', 5 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-21', 2 ,1 )
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES ('XX-XXX', '2019-04-25', 1 ,1 )

;WITH cteDistintAccompDates(AC , AccompDate) AS
(
SELECT AC, AccompDate FROM @tbl1 GROUP BY AccompDate, AC
)
SELECT t1.AC, t1.AccompDate, SUM(t2.Fhours), SUM(t2.FCycles)
FROM @tbl1 t1 
INNER JOIN @tbl2 t2 ON t1.AC = t2.AC
INNER JOIN cteDistintAccompDates t3 ON t2.FlyDate = t3.AccompDate 
AND t1.AccompDate >= t2.FlyDate
GROUP BY t1.AC, t1.AccompDate

AC  AccompDate  Fhours FCycles
XX-XXX  2019-04-07  9   5
XX-XXX  2019-04-08  15  6
XX-XXX  2019-04-21  22  8
XX-XXX  2019-04-25  23  9
```

Comment: Thanks, but the example that I've presented is just a sqmple. There is several rows to sum.

Comment: The above method will work for any number of rows.  I just used your sample data because it would be more straightforward. If you want to parameterize the AC and FlightDate, just add a where clause to the final select.